# Block animations in answers!

Tags: support

When I search for a problem in Stack Exchange, I often see an answer in which the answering person uses a looping animated overlay to show how to go through a procedure. Unfortunately this may cover the text underneath. I could not figure out how get rid of the animated overlays.

There must be a simple solution!

For those who *can* see the covered text:

[image]

Comment: The text *underneath?* Can you show us an example?

Comment: I find animation frustrating when there's no scrubbing control to go to a specific part and pause there. And especially when it's graphical stuff for text... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: kaya3, try this one: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317992/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-path-of-a-folder-in-macos

Comment: It might make sense to replace "cover the text underneath" with "make it less obvious that there is text underneath", slightly less ambiguous that way (I like I assume others thought you meant the image literally covered the text making it impossible to see)

Comment: Clive - Did you look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317992/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-path-of-a-folder-in-macos ? The first answer is covered by the animation. I think "cover the text underneath" is just that. And I want to see that text.

Comment: @Timm I can see the text just fine…

Comment: Thomas Markov - I put up the animation. Can you still see the text behind it?

Comment: At least for me, the only text hidden by the animation in [the answer you linked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/318007/275113) is ... the animation. The animation that's there is a screen recording of a context menu with some text hidden behind the context menu. In other words, the only text that's hidden by the animation is within the animation itself. It's not a problem with the Stack Exchange answer.

Comment: Yes that's the one I looked at @Timm, same for me as others, nothing's hidden. Have you tried in a different browser, disabling extensions, etc?

Comment: I feel like we need some red freehand circles here

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about by "the text underneath" or "cover the text underneath" or why you call images/gifs "overlays" or what that Q&A post screenshot image or its Q&A post are supposed to be showing about that. (Are you maybe talking about accessibility alt text? Or the URL that the image is coming from? The text in a window that was underneath a popup when a screenshot was taken, that isn't even in the screenshot gif that the post contains?) PS Unfortunately browsers can offer poor functionality for dealing with gifs.

Comment: Here's a gif of the [entire answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBcGz.gif), because your example still picture doesn't show all of it, possibly significantly. There's an opening line, "In macOS holding…", then a gif [within a gif now;) then a closing paragraph, "To copy a file…". Which bit do you perceive as 'covered', 'hidden' or 'underneath'?

Answer (score 3):

The animation in the answer you linked is a file of type [GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format).

You might ask in [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) how to disable animations in Apple hardware and software and third-party software running in Apple hardware. Also, you might ask them how to see each static image the animation uses.

The above is because how embedded images are shown is a feature that depends on the user's system.

Also, you might give feedback to the answer author about this specific animation and discuss this case in [Ask Different Meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com).